# Moving Object in ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, scrollviewer

I'm using the MVVM setup, for my app and I'm using an scrollViewer to scroll around an map. On this map I have an unit which I'd like to move around when I select it. However when I select the unit my ScrollViewer is still activated, is there an way to work around the scrollViewer or deactivate it such that I can move the unit around. I already tried changing the ManipulationModeProperty to Control, but thius makes the unit lag  when I move it around.

My ScrollViewer is:

```
 <ScrollViewer Width="768" Height="380" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
        <View:Map/>
 </ScrollViewer>
```

The unit where I apply the manipulation is:

```
 public void ManStart(ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
    {

        myScrollViewer.SetValue(ScrollViewer.ManipulationModeProperty, ManipulationMode.Control);

    public void ManDelta(ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {

        Point fingerPosition = e.DeltaManipulation.Translation;

        Unit.x = fingerPosition.X + ChampModelSel.x;
        Unit.y = fingerPosition.Y + ChampModelSel.y;

    }

public void ManCompleted(ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        var myScrollViewer = FindParentOfType<ScrollViewer>(ChampViewModel) as        ScrollViewer;
        myScrollViewer.SetValue(ScrollViewer.ManipulationModeProperty, ManipulationMode.System);

    }
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure but look into mouse capture for ui elements

Comment: *is there an way to work around the scrollViewer or deactivate it such that I can move the unit around?* Yes, it's called [Drag and Drop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Sheridan I tried following the link you added, but for the windows phine, I cant get the DragDrop.DoDragDrop(), is this because I'm missing an using or reference?

Comment: Please refer to [this](http://www.edumobile.org/windowsphone/windows-phone-development/drag-and-drop-example-in-windows-phone/) Drag and Drop example for Windows Phone

Comment: @sthotakura I did try and follow the example, but this doesn't solve the problem. Once I move outside of the object the ScrollViewer takes over, thus only translating the object from where I started from to where the object ends. It's basicaly the same as I've done already. Any ideas to move the object in the scrollViewer?

Comment: may be using a canvas inside a scrollviewer will help you to move a unit....

Comment: @SALMANKHAN We've already got an canvas in <View:Map/>

Comment: Could you tell us more what you mean with those units? Futhermore could you write a demo and upload it somewhere online (github.com, dropbox.com..) I think I have an idea though I need more code please :)

Comment: @dev hedgehog The unit is basically just an object which I'd like to move around, while i'm in the scrollViewer. I've got an demo at:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/yqe98wh6mhxqtby/didvpdKRBL

When you move the unit around it works fine if, you're using the emulator, but when you use the device you'll experience some lag.

Comment: @devhedgehog didn't include you right

Comment: Thanks for uploading your project. I will take a look at it today. :)

Comment: I am sorry but my visual studio is not able to even load your project... Is demo some different project type?

Comment: @devhedgehog it is windows phone project. So you need windows 8, and the windows phone SDK

Comment: Yea I know and for whatever reason VS2012 fixed managed to load project if I start it as admin however there are still errors not letting me run the app. I will stay on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution for the problem myself. Because I set the ManipulationMode to control, I guess I disable some propertys which end up giving an lag when you move your object. So I ended up trying to make a storyboard when ever I move my object, which fixed the problem and gives me a nice smooth motion when I select the object I wish to move. What I did was I went into my ManDelta:

```
 public void ManDelta(ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
{

    Point fingerPosition = e.DeltaManipulation.Translation;

    Unit.x = fingerPosition.X + ChampModelSel.x;
    Unit.y = fingerPosition.Y + ChampModelSel.y;

}
```

and added some storyboard from the code behind, using this http://www.buzzfrog.se/index.php/2013/06/create-storyboards-in-code-for-windows-phone/ as a guide line. The ManDelta occurs every time I select the object and activate the ManipulationDelta

Answer (score 0):

Does the Unit have a property of Zindex? If yes, set Zindex of Scrollviewer and try setting the Unit ZIndex to a higher value than Scrollviewer.

Comment: didn't work, I used the Canvas.Zindex to set the z index of the scrollviewer, but didnt' work

Answer (score 0):

How about something like creating a global Map variable lets say named MyMap.

When you navigate to a page that contains your map and do (App.Curren as App).MyMap = //your map on the page.

When you do MouseDown and it is being triggered in "when I select the unit" you block all moving allowances of the map in

```
(App.Current as App).MyMap.IsScrollable = false; //or something like that.
```

So that map couldn't scroll when your "UNIT" is in MouseDown state and only "UNIT" was movable. And on MouseUp in "UNIT" undo the:

```
(App.Current as App).MyMap.IsScrollable = true;
```